# How Stop the timer after check rows in a database in c#?

Tags: c#, timer, windows-services

I have a method that check for records in a database and a timer that starts the method every 10 seconds. I check if a new record was inserted in a table and get these values to send emails.

The problem is, if has sended the email 1 time, it is no stop the timer and sends email every 10 seconds. To "solve" this i used an IF to check if the ID of the table was different, and partially i "resolved" the problem. And now, there is a new problem, because the result of the Select with joins query, returns much values and only the ID of that table is repeated, but the other fields are not, like this image:

[image]

As you can see, the ID of the table is 16, but the other ID are 2, 3, 4.

With my first solution, only sends email to the first row and ignore the others rows.  Thats my problem, because i need to sends emails to the other rows. How can i do that?

This is my code (i use Windows Service):

```
      public partial class GaxTankAlerts : ServiceBase
  {
    private string conn = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DBCatalog;Integrated Security=false;User ID=GAX;Password=****;";
    private Timer scheduleTimer = null;
    private bool bandera;
    private string id = "";
    private string estatusAlerta = "";
    private DateTime fechaAlerta;

    public GaxTankAlerts()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      if (!EventLog.SourceExists("AlertService"))
      {
        EventLog.CreateEventSource("AlertService", "AlertLog");
      }
      eventLogEmail.Source = "AlertService";
      eventLogEmail.Log = "AlertLog";

      scheduleTimer = new Timer();
      scheduleTimer.Interval = 10000;

      scheduleTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(scheduleTimer_Elapsed);
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {

      bandera = true;
      scheduleTimer.Start();
      eventLogEmail.WriteEntry("El servicio ha iniciado");
      //GetAlerts();
    }

    protected void scheduleTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
      //if (bandera == true) {
      //  GetAlerts();
      //  //lastRun = DateTime.Now;
      //  bandera = false;
      //}
      eventLogEmail.WriteEntry("Comprobando si hay registros nuevos...");
      if (bandera == true)
      {
        GetAlerts();
      }



    }

    public void GetAlerts()
    {
      var path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "EmailTemplate\\Email.html";
      string body = File.ReadAllText(path);
      try
      {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn))
        {
          SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[General].[GetAlertas]", con);
          cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


          con.Open();
          SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
          {
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
              while (dr.Read())
              {

                if (dr["ID"].ToString() != id)
                {

                  id = dr["ID"].ToString();
                  if (dr["EstatusAlerta"].ToString() != estatusAlerta)
                  {
                    estatusAlerta = dr["EstatusAlerta"].ToString();
                    using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage())
                    {
                     //Sends emails

                    }

                  }
                }

                //if (dr["EstatusAlerta"].ToString() != idReg)
                //{
                //  idReg = dr["EstatusAlerta"].ToString();
                //  bandera = true;
                //}
                //else {
                //  bandera = false;
                //}

              }
            }
          }
          dr.Close();
          con.Close();
        }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        eventLogEmail.WriteEntry(ex.Message.ToString());
      }
    }
```

Thank you.